# How to make the site remember the choice?

Tags: html, css

I made a simple website that includes two language versions, one Turkish and one English, my index page is a page that offers Turkish | English link directing into index-tr and index-en.
My question is how to make the index page remember what did the certain IPs selected when they first accessed the site. I mean, if I selected Turkish for the first time when I access the site another time it should remember that I've selected Turkish and should not direct me to the index page but instead, it should open index-tr.

I've used HTML and CSS only, no Javascript included.

I hope I made it clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is rather impossible for `HTML` and `CSS` only.

Comment: You have to do that by either javascript or at the server (which checks the choice made)

Comment: Umm, can you provide a code for me then? I am new to HTML and CSS, I don't know any of Javascript yet.

Comment: save the first choice into the localstorage via js. On load check the localstorage and if you've found a choice then redirect the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store properties in `HTML` or `CSS` to be remembered for a period of time.

You have to use `JavaScript` or something server side, like `PHP`.

With `JavaScript` you could use `localStorage`.

> The localStorage property allows you to access a local Storage object.
>   localStorage is similar to sessionStorage. The only difference is
>   that, while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data
>   stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the browsing session
>   ends—that is, when the browser is closed.

You can write something like this

```
localStorage.setItem('language', 'tr') // Turkish language
```

You can overwrite this value by just overwriting the language with `setItem()`

```
localStorage.setItem('language', 'en') // English language
```

Now you can do something with it.

```
if(localStorage.getItem('language') == 'tr') {
    // Language it Turkish, redirect or what ever JS code here.
} else {
    // Language is not Turkish, but something other then 'tr'    
}
```

**More documentation and example's you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**

Comment: What if user is visiting site for very first time and `localStorage` is `null`?

Comment: Well, thats on the developer. He can show a popup with 2 options, `which site do you want to visit? ..` then give `turkish` and `english` or just set a default value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with `HTML` `CSS` only, you have to use JavaScript,

Use `localStorage`

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined"){
  localStorage.setItem('lang', 'tur');
} else localStorage.getItem('lang')
```

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with html and css, you have to do it with or at the server 
(cookies in php)